# How to show plots in Stack Overflow questions

Tags: support, images, formatting

What is the best way to attach a plot, or a link to a plot (or image) to a Stack Overflow question? I have tried attaching as an image but to no avail. I believe there is a platform to do this. Does anyone know what that platform is called?

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Comment: You need a minimum reputation score to post an image with your question on StackOverflow (I believe the minimum score is 10)

Comment: Your test worked (we can see the image link). For directly showing the pictures you need some amount of reputation as MrFlick said.

Comment: Thank you Stephen and Mr Flick I am on my way.

Answer (score 2):

Copy the image straight from RStudio's viewer (as an image), and then paste into your Stack Overflow post.